# redirect to mobile version

Tags: javascript, mobile

I've just created a mobile version for my site and I want to redirect users to it. so far i've added the lines of code below to redirect users from the main index page to the mobile index page:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  if (screen.width <= 800) {
    window.location = "mobile.site.name";
  }
  //-->
</script>
```

This works, however how do I redirect users from let's say site.name/contact.html  to  to m.site.com/contact.html ?

Can you please help ?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend ASKING your user if they want to get redirected as opposed to just redirecting them.

Comment: Thank you for your input but that was not the help I needed. Even if they agree with being redirected to the mobile version of the site, i still need the technical solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You should Do this stuff in your .htaccess-file. Mod_rewrite is the solution. Have a look.